# calling REST websrevice via Android

Tags: java, android, web-services

I'm currently calling a local .json file in my Android app using the following line

InputStream inputStream = context.getAssets().open("cyclist.json");

I simply want to switch it to pull the .json from a webservice instead.  What is the best way to do this?

Comment: u can also use .net webservice if u hv server

Comment: Sorry as I should have been more specific.  I've already created the webservice, I just need to know how can I change the above call to not pull form the local file, but to call the webservice?

Comment: http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-json-parsing-tutorial/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Supposing you already set up a server to respond to requests, I would try something like this:

```
URL url = new URL("http://www.mydomain.com/slug");
URLConnection urlConnection = url.openConnection();
InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(urlConnection.getInputStream());
try {
 readStream(in);
} finally {
 in.close();
}
```

See [URLConnection](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/URLConnection.html) for details.

I know Android enforces limitations in downloading stuff from a server. You might have to execute the code in another thread, using the [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html). Again, I'm not sure if this is required for your particular purpose.

Comment: URLConnection is not the recommended way to do this. Use `AndroidHttpClient` instead to enforce reasonable timeouts and a much better interface (though that's a personal preference), if you need low-level access.

Comment: I agree with you, but it depends on what he is trying to do exactly. If he's simply downloading a file, I prefer my method as I find it more readable. If a low-level access is required, I'd go with [AndroidHttpClient](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/http/AndroidHttpClient.html)

Answer (score 1):

Please, please, don't reinvent the wheel.

Use existing libraries [Volley by Google](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/volley/) ([video from I/O talk](https://developers.google.com/events/io/sessions/325304728)), [Retrofit by Square](https://github.com/square/retrofit), [RoboSpice](https://github.com/octo-online/robospice) and countless others are there to serve you. Further, [search before posting](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=android+rest+library)